# Why does my ceiling fan run slowly?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a ceiling fan where the old fan had 2 wall switches (one for fan and one for the light)  I read a previous post related to this question, but does not apply to my situation. The wires in the ceiling box are the same (black, white, green, and red) but no blue.  The new fan (with remote and light)) has only black, white, and green wires.  When connecting the new fan wires to the same color wires in the box, the new fan runs at a very slow speed , but does not respond to the remote, other than on and off.  Anyone know what the problem is?
Oh, and the white wire from the box comes off of two white wires, one of which was hot, even when both wall switches were off. I believe it came from a common white connected to another ceiling light in the next room. When I disconnected the joint [image]

The new fan is a Harbor breeze model saratoga #00798.

Comment: What's the make and model of the new fan? The same info for the old fan might be relevant too. And please [edit] your question with a link to the previous post you mentioned so that we know not to suggest things that have already been suggested.

Comment: When you say one of the white wires is hot, how did you discover this? Did you get a specific voltage reading from a multimeter, or just a buzz from a non-contact voltage tester?

Comment: Are you sure they're both wall switches and not dimmers?

Comment: No. they are both on/off switches. One operated the fan, the other the motor. fan speed was controlled by a chain on the fan.

Comment: When my fan slowed down, it was because the capacitor, which delays phase for half the magnets, had gone bad. Should not be bad in a new fan, but worth a check. The lamp store should have them, If there are enough self-fixers in your area. I happen to have a capacitance meter. Looks like they can be had cheap: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=capacitance+meter&t=ffsb&ia=products

Answer (score 1):

It's also worthy to check and see that the fan itself has its own speed control pull switch *at the fan itself...* Or possibly some dip switch settings in the fan, like speed options and even possibly other settings like hz. settings... I'm guessing of course, and I may have missed something in your original post, but especially if this fan has a pull chain speed switch in it, the fan itself must be in the high speed position *at the fan,* especially if you have a wall switch associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it was wired correctly the house wiring would be:
Green: Ground.
White: Neutral.
Black: Switched hot from fan switch for fan.
Red: Switched hot from light switch for light.
You would connect to green, white and one of either black or red to the new fan.  The fan may have it's own pull chain speed switch which could be left on a lower speed.
If you place AC voltmeter leads between the white and green wires you should get very low voltage, say 0-2 volts.  Do NOT disconnect the grouped white wires with the power on or you may burn up something they feed.  (Long story)